# Should I commit .testsettings and .vsdmi files to the repository?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I usually don't commit unnecessary files, such as `.user` and `.suo` files, to the repository.
I'm unsure about whether `.testsettings` and `.vsdmi` files are regenerated by Visual Studio if absent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you should commit those files as they contain Visual Studio unit testing and code coverage settings for the project.

Answer (score 7):

I found a [contrary opinion](http://web.archive.org/web/20110308085203/http://arcware.net/vs2005-vsmdi-file-should-not-be-under-source-control/) while researching this.  To be honest I'm a bit torn as the fellow in the link makes a good bit of sense.

EDIT: Updated link to archive.org version, as the original post seems to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

I tested here and I found out that while those files aren't regenerated while running tests, they aren't missed.

The only error I ran into with their absention was that when I try to open them it shows an error message box.

I think I will commit them to source control from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.
They contain test execution settings, test lists etc. As such, they are an integral part of your project, just like e.g. App.config.

Thomas