# Visual Studio 2012 default .testsettings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have solution containing a Local.testsettings file. In Visual Studio 2012 we must select manually in each development machine the active .testsettings file to use.

[image]

I can not understand how to tell to Visual Studio 2012 that the solution default .testsettings file is the Local.testsettings and to be able to setup that information in some versionned file (.sln or other) so that other users does not need to setup manualy the active settings file.

Comment: is it committed to your code repository?

Comment: kind of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070338/should-i-commit-testsettings-and-vsdmi-files-to-the-repository

Answer (score 1):

Edit solution file and add following

```
 Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{9BEFB796-EFAA-45DD-810E-8785A8F88FB0}"
        ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
            CommonAssemblyInfo.cs = CommonAssemblyInfo.cs
            DevBuild.testsettings = DevBuild.testsettings
            Local.testsettings = Local.testsettings
            TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings = TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings
        EndProjectSection
    EndProject
```

and check in this file and test setting files

Comment: Sorry but the defaut selected testsettings was not set in the mnu TEST>Test settings after applying your modification

Answer (score 1):

Even in Visual Studio 2013 update 4 (the latest version at the time of posting this answer), the chosen `.testsettings` file is not retained.

You have to select the `.testsettings` file manually each time you open up Visual Studio.